# How to get this type of animation on figma?

Tags: figma

https://code-apj-noida.github.io/home/

I want this type of random lines moving and disappearing in my figma prototype of a website, is it possible to get this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, It is possible in Figma. I will provide the solution step by step with an example.

**Step 01-**
First, go to youtube and search "Technology Network Backgrounds" and copy the video URL

**Step 02-**
Go to [savefrom.net](https://en.savefrom.net/176/) and paste your video link into the search bar. Then click *Download*

**Step 03-**
After downloading your video and go to [ezgif.com](https://ezgif.com/)  and click the video to gif option. Then drag and drop your video file to the space. And click upload.
Next, you will see some settings like start time-end time. Set end time to 10s or 20s and click **Convert to GIF**. Next, you will see your gif below. Right-click on it and give save as an image. Select your file path and you will see "video.gif" change it to "Video.jpg" and download it as an image.

**Step 04** Go to Figma and from the menu select place an image option. Select the jpg image you downloaded before and put it into your frame. After adjustments run the prototype. You will get a playing background on Figma. That is one of the easiest ways.

> Here I did this sample landing page for you. [Landing Page Sample on
> Figma](https://www.figma.com/file/Gg8ihNjITJDe1d5O3G4aED/Untitled?node-id=0%3A1)